# Git - Change List (svn) Equivalent

Tags: git, svn, version-control, changelist

We used svn for years, and have recently switched over to Git. We used to use change lists in svn for a specific purpose. They are similar to global ignores but not exactly the same. A global ignore tells svn not to add files that fit the pattern, but if a file is already added to version control, the ignore won't do anything. This is the same thing in Git. Git ignore files tell Git to ignore files that match a given pattern, but *only* if they have not yet been added to version control.

Change lists in svn allowed us to specify files that had already been added in to version control. Once the files had been added to the change list, svn would ignore these files on commit. The basic advantage of this is that you can freely edit certain files without the fear of accidentally commiting a change that you don't want to go in to the main code base. A good example scenario is when you want to work with a specific customer's configuration and add customer specific references to your project files that should not exist in the core code base.

Git has the concept of stashes which is different again. We can store deltas in a stash in a local repo. These can be freely applied, pushed, or popped which solves one part of the problem. However, when we do a commit (through some gui tool - tortoise git, gitkraken, VS), these files will still show up in the list of files that Git wants to commit. I don't want them to show up because I will more than likely make a mistake and commit them accidentally.

Is there some way to achieve change list like functionality in Git?

Note: I really don't want to have to do this through the command line. I use a combination of Visual Studio, Git Kraken, and Tortoise Git. I like the Gui system. I don't want to have to run a command at the command prompt which will automatically commit my changes while avoiding the files I specify.

Comment: your usage of change list is actually not a standard SVN feature iirc. The special change list (something like ignore-on-commit?) is a feature of TortoiseSVN, and it is not working in all SVN clients (I remember some SVN client did follow same convention though)

Comment: @Melbourne Developer, please mark the answer which helps you solve the problem. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article in the answer that @Marina - MSFT posted led me to the answer:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/ignore-files

This stops tracking files already committed in Git:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

The resumes tracking of files already committed in Git:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

I didn't want to have to run things at the command line so I made a batch file which stops tracking all the files I want to ignore. I just double click on it when I need it. Git no longer pays attention to these files. It works exactly the same was a change lists in svn.

Answer (score 1):

In vs, if you want to ignore a file which has already added in version control, you need use the command `git rm --cached filename` assist you to achieve your goal, so that it can be really ignored (you can refer [ignore files in vs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/ignore-files)). So the steps like:

1. Add filename in .gitignore
2. In command line, use `git rm --cached filename`
3. Edit the file, so the changes can’t be tracked

The command `git update-index --assume-unchanged filename` is tepportarily ignore a file. When switch to other branch, you need `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged filename` firstly. That means it only works for a short time and the file is actually version controlled by git. If it meet your needs, of cause you can use it instead.

But if you don't need to do version control for the file any more, the first method is needed.

Comment: This didn't look quite right so I did some digging on the article you posted. It recommends this: git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename> . Why wouldn't you use this command instead? It works well for me.

Comment: I update the difference in my answer for your refer.